# Is wudu necessary to offer namaz in Masjid e haraam?

Tags: salat

I am in MAKKAH to offer Umrah. The place for Wudu is really far from Bait-ALLAH.

Comment: Wudu is necessary for namaz wherever you do!

Comment: Well your Questions sounds a bit strange: Because of course you need to do ritual washing or wudu (or if not possible something equal which compensate it like tayamum) before performing any prayer any where in the world. And i think if you enter the Mosque known as Bait-Allah al Haram intently without wudu this might be permissible, but to some extent shows no respect for your creator!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you must do wudhu. Allah says in the Quran:

> يَا أَيُّهَا الَّذِينَ آمَنُوا إِذَا قُمْتُمْ إِلَى الصَّلَاةِ
>   فَاغْسِلُوا وُجُوهَكُمْ وَأَيْدِيَكُمْ إِلَى الْمَرَافِقِ وَامْسَحُوا
>   بِرُءُوسِكُمْ وَأَرْجُلَكُمْ إِلَى الْكَعْبَيْنِ ۚ وَإِن كُنتُمْ
>   جُنُبًا فَاطَّهَّرُوا ۚ وَإِن كُنتُم مَّرْضَىٰ أَوْ عَلَىٰ سَفَرٍ أَوْ
>   جَاءَ أَحَدٌ مِّنكُم مِّنَ الْغَائِطِ أَوْ لَامَسْتُمُ النِّسَاءَ
>   فَلَمْ تَجِدُوا مَاءً فَتَيَمَّمُوا صَعِيدًا طَيِّبًا فَامْسَحُوا
>   بِوُجُوهِكُمْ وَأَيْدِيكُم مِّنْهُ ۚ مَا يُرِيدُ اللَّهُ لِيَجْعَلَ
>   عَلَيْكُم مِّنْ حَرَجٍ وَلَٰكِن يُرِيدُ لِيُطَهِّرَكُمْ وَلِيُتِمَّ
>   نِعْمَتَهُ عَلَيْكُمْ لَعَلَّكُمْ تَشْكُرُونَ
>
> O you who have believed, when you rise to [perform] prayer, wash your
>   faces and your forearms to the elbows and wipe over your heads and
>   wash your feet to the ankles. And if you are in a state of janabah,
>   then purify yourselves. But if you are ill or on a journey or one of
>   you comes from the place of relieving himself or you have contacted
>   women and do not find water, then seek clean earth and wipe over your
>   faces and hands with it. Allah does not intend to make difficulty for
>   you, but He intends to purify you and complete His favor upon you that
>   you may be grateful.

thus, making wudhu is necessary. If it is too far to do wudhu, buy some leather socks. Then make wudhu once in the morning, and put the socks on. For the rest of the day, when you need to do wudhu, just wipe over the socks. Also, in the wudhu, the compulsory acts are washing the face and arms, wiping the head, and washing the feet (or wiping the leather socks if you have them on) just once. Thus, you can take a small bottle of water with you and make wudhu near the baytullah if you broke your wudhu.

I hope this helps

Comment: Would you please explain more what you mean by " buy some leather socks. Then make wudhu once in the morning, and put the socks on. For the rest of the day, **when you need to do wudhu, just wipe over the socks**"

Comment: @Atata by leather socks he may mean the "Khufayn"

Comment: @Medi1Saif I know what it means, I just did not understand the part "when you need to do wudu, just wipe over the socks". I know when you are wearing the khufayn you can wipe over them when you do the **full wudu**